# visual basic 2015: how to change text of a dynamically created label with a button click event

Tags: vb.net

I have a dynamically created tabpage where I have placed dynamically created a button and label. I'm trying to figure out how to change the label.text with the button.click event. Everything works correctly until I add in the With/End With to change the label text in the button click subroutine. This is my first try at dynamically programming (hobby of mine, so trying to learn), but I do have a specific end goal for this application. Any thoughts on how to fix this problem?

```
Private Sub initialize_Button()
    Dim button_Mybutton As New Button
    With button_Mybutton
        .Name = "button_My_Button"
        .AutoSize = True
        .Text = "Calculate"
        .Visible = True
        .Top = 200
        .Left = 10
    End With
    AddHandler button_Mybutton.Click, AddressOf Me.button_Click
    Me.Controls.Add(button_Mybutton)
End Sub

Protected Sub button_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    MsgBox("Button Clicked")
    With label_Test
        .text = "Test Confirmed"
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub label_Test_Output()
    Dim label_Test As New Label
    With label_Test
        .Name = "label_Test"
        .Top = 200
        .Left = 100
        .AutoSize = True
        .Text = "Label Test"
        .Visible = True
    End With
    Me.Controls.Add(label_Test)
End Sub
```

Comment: You declare the label in that horribly named `label_Test_Output`method, so that is the only place that reference exists.  Either fish the lable back out of the controls collection or hold onto a reference to it (declare it at the form level - use an array if there are more than one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the declaration of the controls outside the methods, to the class level. Then you can access them from anywhere in the class.

```
Private button_Mybutton As Button
Private label_Test As Label

Private Sub initialize_Button()
    button_Mybutton = New Button()
    With button_Mybutton
        .Name = "button_My_Button"
        .AutoSize = True
        .Text = "Calculate"
        .Visible = True
        .Top = 200
        .Left = 10
    End With
    AddHandler button_Mybutton.Click, AddressOf Me.button_Click
    Me.Controls.Add(button_Mybutton)
End Sub

Protected Sub button_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    MsgBox("Button Clicked")
    If label_Test IsNot Nothing Then
        With label_Test
            .text = "Test Confirmed"
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub label_Test_Output()
    label_Test = New Label()
    With label_Test
        .Name = "label_Test"
        .Top = 200
        .Left = 100
        .AutoSize = True
        .Text = "Label Test"
        .Visible = True
    End With
    Me.Controls.Add(label_Test)
End Sub
```

You should also check if the label is created when accessing it, since there is a possibility that you can click the button before calling `label_Test_Output`. Added null check to handler.

Comment: Moving the declarations to the class level did the trick, thanks everyone for the help!